# Django- how to add user profile permissions based for selected users

Tags: python, django, user-profile, django-permissions

In my Django app, I have a `user_profile` model (below).
Each user has an `is_adm` boolean value:

user_profile/models.py:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField('username', max_length=50, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField('email address', unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    is_adm = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Separately I have a `posts` model for blog posts. There is an admin panel for this model where you can add a new Post instance. You can also update, delete or view other Post instances there.

posts/models.py:

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300, default='')
    publish_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    copy = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
    link = models.URLField(blank=True)
    source = models.TextField(default='', blank=True)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I want the ability for `is_adm` = True users to be able to:

- add a Post model instance in the admin panel
- delete any Post model instance in the admin panel
- view any Post model instance in the admin panel
- edit fields in the `Posts` admin panel

I know that Django has Permissions and Authorization:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization

But how do I add these methods like: `has_view_permission()`, `has_add_permission()`, `has_change_permission()` and `has_delete_permission()`...

... for `is_adm` = True users so that they can add, delete, view and change Post model instances through the Post admin panel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose you two solutions. I am sure about the first one because I use it on a personal project. However, I never tested the second one.

### Create Admin Manager

You can create a specific admin manager for your `Posts` model and override the methods which manage the permissions.

The following code gives all permissions if the user of the request has `is_adm` to `True`, otherwise it gives the default permission value.

```py
from django.contrib.admin import ModelAdmin, register

@register(Posts)
class PostsAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        if request.user.is_adm:
            return True
        return super().has_add_permission(request)

    def has_view_permission(self, request, obj):
        if request.user.is_adm:
            return True
        return super().has_view_permission(request, obj)

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj):
        if request.user.is_adm:
            return True
        return super().has_change_permission(request, obj)

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj):
        if request.user.is_adm:
            return True
        return super().has_delete_permission(request, obj)
```

### Modify your User

An other solution could be to override the `has_perm` method of your custom `User` which is inherits from `PermissionsMixin`.

The following code should give all permissions if the user has `is_adm` to `True` and the object is an instance of `Posts`.

```py
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField('username', max_length=50, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField('email address', unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    is_adm = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        if self.is_adm and isinstance(obj, Posts):
            return True
        return super().has_perm(perm, obj)
```

Comment: thanks. One thing I realize is that I need to give the `is_adm` = True user access to the root admin panel first.  For example the URL to the root admin is url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls) but right now only superusers can see that url (admin/) do you know how I can change this?

Comment: This root admin panel is not restricted to superusers but staffusers with the default user model. I do not find where the admin panel is restricted. You can try to add this (copied from `AbstractUser`) `is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff status'), default=False)` in your `User` model. Another solution could be to inherit from `AbstractUser` instead of `AbstractBaseUser` and `PermissionsMixin`.

Comment: Also- is this extra return line in each method necessary? (meaning, can it be optional?): return super().has_delete_permission(request, obj)

Comment: This line is necessary because the function must return a boolean. This line is here to have the default behaviour if the user is not `adm`, i.e. it will return `True` if it is a superuser or if the user specifically has the permission. You could remove the line but then a superuser would not have the permission.